# error #1006 value is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem with my project.
I use SWFLoader to load a .swf file and addEvent when it completed:

```
function completeHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
    var mainObj:Object = Object(loader.rawContent.CTN_PROFILES);
    var obj : Object = { };
    mainObj.playerOptions(obj);
}
```

but always get this Error:#1006 value is not a function.
And it happened at :

```
mainObj.playerOptions(obj);
```

When i trace mainObj at console, i get all of its methods:

```
{Profiles}
Extends: {Object}
function tabInfoClickHandle(flash.events::MouseEvent):*
function closePopup(flash.events::MouseEvent):*
function playerOptions(Object):*
function defaultTab():*
function tabCodeClickHandle(flash.events::MouseEvent):*
function update(Object):*
function acceptProfile(flash.events::MouseEvent):*
function getGift(flash.events::MouseEvent):*
```

I've tried so many way but cannot call any methods, even casting it to MovieClip.But in another project, i've used exactly this code and it worked!I've read many topic but cannot find out how.
Is there any solution for my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `var mainObj1:MovieClip = loader.rawContent as MovieClip; var mainObj:MovieClip = mainObj1.CTN_PROFILES;`

Comment: Please post the Profiles class.

Comment: @Sudan: I've try but it has error #1034 at: `var mainObj:MovieClip = mainObj1.CTN_PROFILES;
`

Comment: Profiles class is too long so i cant post it. I think Profile class is fine, because i'm using it in my game online and has no problem. My project i'm talking about in my question is a version of this game.
I built the .swf file by Adobe flash pro, and here is action at frame 1: `var CTN_PROFILES = new Profiles(this);`

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I rebuilt the .swf file and it works fine.